# Codeigniter: 404 Page Not Found: /index

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Codeigniter is throwing the `404 Page Not Found: /index` error for all the 404 routes whereas It should throw `404 Page Not Found: controller/action` instead.

**Current Error**

```
ERROR - 2020-03-12 13:54:44 --> 404 Page Not Found: /index
```

**Expected Error**

```
ERROR - 2020-03-12 13:54:44 --> 404 Page Not Found: controller/action
```

Please find my code and configuration below

**OS**: Windows 10 (64Bit)

**Mod_Rewrite**: I have enabled Mod_Rewrite Module In Apache

**Codeigniter Version**: 3.1 (HMVC Architecture)

**PHP version**: 5.6.32

**public\.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^vendor/(.*)?$ / [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

**application\config\config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://site.local/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Let me know if any additional information is required.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to use a controller named `index`?

Comment: @JavierLarroulet No. It is throwing the 404 Page Not Found: /index error for **all the 404 routes** whereas It should throw 404 Page Not Found: controller/action instead.